# What special properties does 18% gray color have in photography?

Tags: color

I keep seeing 18% gray color backgrounds being used in different areas of photography. What's special about it, why 18% and not 17 or 19?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very smart question!

[This link](http://www.bythom.com/graycards.htm) tells the whole story.

> It appears that the 18% gray value comes from the print world. On
>   printed material, it's claimed that the half way point between black
>   and white reflects 18% of the light. So a neutral gray (not whitish or
>   blackish) is 18% gray. It very well may be that Kodak continues to
>   market 18% gray cards because it is easy to produce and monitor this
>   reflectance in production.

However:

> Light meters are calibrated at the factory using ANSI standards. The
>   standard has always been for a luminance value that is roughly
>   equivalent to the reflectance of 12% gray.

And notice this comment:

> [...] the 18% myth is so ingrained in the photography world that virtually
>   everyone just parrots the party line. This includes Nikon USA, who
>   will tell you that their camera meters are calibrated to 18% gray
>   (talk to the Nikon Japan camera engineers, and you get a different
>   story, as they'll respond "yes" when you ask if the Nikon meters are
>   calibrated to ANSI standards; and yes, I had the chance to ask them a
>   few years ago when I was in Japan).

So the answer is 18% is easy to reproduce in print, and light meters were either calibrated to true ANSI 12% and used some correction with the 18% gray *or* they were calibrated to 18%.

These days you take a 18% gray object and since RGB sensors sense the color, they can handle 18% gray easily. In fact, they can handle *any* gray if you only want to correct color - the brighter it is the better though, without overexposure, as more light allows for more precise metering. The reason why: the color space is being adjusted with this, but exposure is adjusted using the per-image metering.